# Get all sharepoint sites in a site collection to which user has access using Javascript client object model

Tags: 2010, client-object-model

I want to display all sites in a site collection using JSOM to which user has access to. In other words I only need to find collection of sites to which user has access in a site collection. I am able to get all webs but it doesnt work if user doesnt have permissions to some of web sites.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SP.Web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(query_)` to get the list of sub sites a user has permission on. However, please note that this will return the sub site immediately underneath a site. That is, if you have nested sites several level deep you will need to write a recursion. Here is the sample code:

```
var webCollection = null;
    function runCode() {

        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
            var web = clientContext.get_web();

            this.webCollection = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);

            clientContext.load(this.webCollection);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }
    }

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        var webInfo = 'Child sites of the current site: \n\n';
        var webEnumerator = this.webCollection.getEnumerator();
        while (webEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var web = webEnumerator.get_current();
            webInfo += web.get_title() + '\n';
        }
        console.log(webInfo);
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', runCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the API instead then I would suggest you do the following to return all the sub webs for the current user.

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://example/site/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPWebCollection webCollection = web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SP.Web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246242.aspx) since it returns a security trimmed collection of sub sites (where user has access)

But it only returns sites for one level beneath current site.

**Example**

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var webs = ctx.get_web().getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
ctx.load(webs);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
        for(var i=0;i< webs.get_count();i++) {
            var web = webs.getItemAtIndex(i);
            console.log(web.get_title());   
        }
    },
    function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
);
```

If you are interested in all sub webs within a site collection, you could consider the following approach.

```
function getAllSubwebsForCurrentUser(success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
   var result = [];
   var level = 0;
   var getAllSubwebsForCurrentUserInner = function(web,result,success,error) 
   {
      level++;
      var ctx = web.get_context();
      var webs = web.get_webs(); 
      ctx.load(webs,'Include(Title,Webs)');
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < webs.get_count();i++){
                var web = webs.getItemAtIndex(i);
                result.push(web);
                if(web.get_webs().get_count() > 0) {
                   getAllSubwebsForCurrentUserInner(web,result,success,error);
                }   
            }
            level--;
            if (level == 0 && success)
              success(result);  
        },
        error);
   };

   getAllSubwebsForCurrentUserInner(web,result,success,error);    
}
```

Usage

```
getAllSubwebsForCurrentUser(
function(allwebs){
    for(var i = 0; i < allwebs.length;i++){
        console.log(allwebs[i].get_title());   
    }
},
function(sendera,args){
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```